# Rails Model: How to make field read only in Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, model, readonly

I have defined attribute is_first for table items.

In model Item, i want to set value of this attribute based upon whether an item exits before or not.
I don't want is_first attribute to be writeable. Please suggest what should i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to use **attr_readonly** in your model file:

```
attr_readonly :is_first
```

Comment: How to verify if it is allowing write or not. I set value of is_first from rails console, its reflecting same (although not saved yet)

Comment: You should be able to create the record. Then if you try to update the field you shouldn't be able. You can test it in console.

Comment: but in my case i don't want this attribute to be accessible even when i create new record, it should be accessible with model only not accessible outside even for show purpose.

Comment: so maybe you can use a callback like before_save or before_create to let the model allow or not to modify the field.

Comment: i am using callback to set field but to make it inaccessible i have modified property itself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465628/rails-model-how-to-make-a-attribute-protected-or-private-that-is-not-visible-out