# Rails Model: How to make a attribute protected or private that is not visible outside model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, model, private

There are some fields present in table which i don't want to be visible outside?

Like created_on, is_first etc. I want to set value of these fields by using callbacks with in model but not accessible for some one to set it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The standard way to prevent mass-assignment on certain fields is `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

In your case, you would have to add this line in your model:

```
attr_protected :created_on, :is_first
```

Even if you have a form with these fields, their values will be ignored, when used in a new/create call.

Comment: attr_protected doesn't work for my requirement, i suppose mass assignment is different thing of what i need.

Comment: You accepted the answer that doesn't work for you anyway, cool.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_new =(is_new)
     raise 'is_new is immutable!'
end
```

Comment: If you do this, you will have to use define a different attribute writer, and use write_attribute, should you ever need to change that attribute from your application.

Comment: @Teoulas:  I tried this, it worked. I want to access is_new only within model that is for setting its value in callback. so i refer this attribute as is_new rather than by self.is_new thus making it accessible inside model but not outside.

Comment: In this case, you can declare the is_new/is_new= methods as protected or private.